# Validating XML documents with XSD correctly

Tags: c#, .net, xml, schema

As a developer with a good deal of XML consuming and producing experience, I've never really interacted with schemas before.  For the first time this is actually occurring for me.

I've run across a "feature" that I consider more of a bug which is well documented.

When using XDocument.Validate() it seems that there are cases in which the document will be valid if it doesn't match the schema specified.  I feel this is most likely a flaw in my understanding of the relationship between XSDs, XML namespaces, and expected validation processes.

Therefore I submit to you my XML sample, my XSD sample, and my validation code.

XML - this is INTENTIONALLY the wrong document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SuppliesDefinitions 
  xmlns="http://lavendersoftware.org/schemas/SteamGame/Data/Xml/Supplies.xsd">
  <Supply type="Common">
    <Information/>
    <Ritual/>
    <Weapon/>
    <Tool count="1"/>
    <Tool count="2"/>
    <Tool count="3"/>
  </Supply>
  <Supply type="Uncommon">
    <Information/>
    <Weapon/>
    <Tool count="1"/>
    <Tool count="2"/>
    <Tool count="3"/>
    <Tool count="4"/>
  </Supply>
  <Supply type="Rare">
    <Information/>
    <Rune/>
    <Weapon/>
    <Tool count="2"/>
    <Tool count="3"/>
    <Tool count="4"/>
  </Supply>
</SuppliesDefinitions>
```

The XSD used to validate it. (Again, this is intentionally the WRONG document for the above XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Encounters"
    targetNamespace="http://lavendersoftware.org/schemas/SteamGame/Data/Xml/Encounters.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://lavendersoftware.org/schemas/SteamGame/Data/Xml/Encounters.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://lavendersoftware.org/schemas/SteamGame/Data/Xml/Encounters.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:complexType name="ToolType">
    <xs:attribute name="count" use="required" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="TaskType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
      <xs:element name="Weapon"/>
      <xs:element name="Information"/>
      <xs:element name="Tool" type="ToolType"/>
      <xs:element name="Ritual"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="EncounterType">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
      <xs:element name="Task" type="TaskType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="EncounterDefinitions">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="Encounter" type="EncounterType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And finally the validation code.

```
    private static void ValidateDocument(XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(XmlSchemaProvider.GetSchemaStream("Encounters.xsd"))));

        doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
        {
            //This is never hit!
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
            Assert.False(e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error);
        });
    }
```

I was wondering if someone can explain what I am doing wrong.  I feel I'm making some incorrect assumptions about the way this SHOULD be working.  It seems to me using one xsd against a completely unrelated XML document would be invalid.

Comment: Xsd validation usually only generates a warning when the desired schema cannot be found. You are pobably only checking for errors.

Comment: This is not the case here, see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954(v=vs.90).aspx for details on XDocument.Validate.  This particular overload of validate will catch errors and warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no nodes in your XML that can be validated by the schema (namespaces are different). As result it does not report any errors. As far as I know behavior for nodes that are not matched to any schema is allow anything.

You also could set [validation options in XmlReaderSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xe0740a.aspx) to allow warnings:

> **ReportValidationWarnings** - Indicates that events should be reported if a validation warning occurs. A warning is typically issued when there is no DTD or XML Schema to validate a particular element or attribute against. The ValidationEventHandler is used for notification.

Check out [XmlSchemaSet.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x54c5bt.aspx) and [HOW TO: Validate an XML Document by Using Multiple Schemas](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318505) if you expect nodes from multiple namespaces to be present in the XML.

Comment: In this case the real issue is that no schema exists in XmlSchemaSet schemas that matches the schema for the namespace specified in the document root is it not? shouldn't that be enforceable?

Comment: @DanielGreen it is, but I don't remember how... I've added link to reporting warnings so it should let you know about elements that don't have schema.

Comment: That's all well and good, but the current design takes in an XDocument and I'd rather not change that, but loading the stream twice seems wrong as well, especially since in this context it's not clear what to load.

Comment: Having the same issue. This part of .NET really fails on the "principle of least astronishment".

Comment: Also, just to make note, this doesn't actually help at all - the .net validator doesn't consider this a warning either.

Comment: Link " HOW TO: Validate an XML Document by Using Multiple Schemas" doesn't work :(